# Why models.EmbeddedModelField is not working with djongo/django?

Tags: django, mongodb, model, nosql, djongo

**I have class Dimension and Feature. ( Want to create an Embedded Model from Feature to Dimension)**

Documentation: bottom of [page](https://djongo.readthedocs.io/docs/using-django-with-mongodb-data-fields/)

*I keep getting the error:*

> dimension = models.EmbeddedModel
>
> AttributeError: module 'djongo.models' has no attribute
>   'EmbeddedModel'

```
class Dimension(models.Model):

    dimensionName = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.dimensionName


class Feature(models.Model):

    featureName = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    dimension = models.EmbeddedModel(
        model_container=Dimension,
    )
    def __str__(self):
        return self.featureName
```

**Any leads would be appreciated!**

Comment: Were you able to solve it?

Comment: No, it doesn't work. 
It accepts the syntax and it successfully create the migrations, but when I try to migrate, I get an error that it fails to migrate and warns that EmbeddedField might be a badly written custom field. :(

Comment: actually, solved it!! using models.EmbeddedField and adding a default=None

Comment: Glad to hear that. Though  the `default=None` wasn't provided in my answer, if my answer helped with the original question and pointed you to the right direction, a vote up would be appreciated  https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `djongo.models.EmbeddedField` (for djongo==1.3.1) or `djongo.models.EmbeddedModelField` for (djongo==1.2.23)